# npm install fails "invalid version", "every cell calls own pop w/out invisible block"

Tags: node.js, npm

I've installed nvm and then tried to run an npm project as I usually do with "npm start", but I get this failure

```
npm ERR! Invalid version: "10-10-2022 -- 1685 -- every cell calls own pop w/out invisible block"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/roman/.npm/_logs/2022-10-29T11_30_43_298Z-debug.log
```

Logs:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/roman/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/roman/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.17
3 info using node@v14.20.0
4 verbose stack Error: Invalid version: "10-10-2022 -- 1685 -- every cell calls own pop w/out invisible block"
4 verbose stack     at Object.fixVersionField (/Users/roman/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js:191:13)
4 verbose stack     at /Users/roman/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js:32:38
4 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
4 verbose stack     at normalize (/Users/roman/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js:31:15)
4 verbose stack     at final (/Users/roman/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:429:5)
4 verbose stack     at then (/Users/roman/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:161:5)
4 verbose stack     at /Users/roman/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:382:12
4 verbose stack     at /Users/roman/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
4 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:71:3)
5 verbose cwd /Users/roman/Desktop/pycharm_projects/frontend
6 verbose Darwin 21.3.0
7 verbose argv "/Users/roman/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/bin/node" "/Users/roman/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/bin/npm" "start"
8 verbose node v14.20.0
9 verbose npm  v6.14.17
10 error Invalid version: "10-10-2022 -- 1685 -- every cell calls own pop w/out invisible block"
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I tried:

- npm install
- npm upgrade

Nothing worked. I can't even google that, there's no results, please help

Comment: post your `package.json`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Neykuratick/c778a1014f3b946a0411c8686826942e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed nvm (`rm ~/.nvm` or `mv ~/.nvm ~/.nvm_old`) and it just works now

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

- npm install --force

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).